# Overriding a shared library in Linux with LD_PRELOAD

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, gsl, ld-preload

I'm trying to fix a binary that seems to be dynamically linked to an older version of GSL (the GNU Scientific Library):

```
$ ldd my-binary
        ...
        libgsl.so.23 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23 (0x00007fc600d51000)
        ...
```

If I use `LD_PRELOAD` to set a newer version, my understanding was that the older version would be replaced. Instead, I'm just seeing two instances of the same library:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/my/libgsl.so.25.0.0 ldd my-binary
        ...
        /path/to/my/libgsl.so.25.0.0 (0xsomething)
        ...
        libgsl.so.23 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.23 (0x00007fc600d51000)
        ...
```

Is that going to work, or will having them both in there cause problems?

Comment: Usually, unresolved symbols are stored just as a list, independently from the required libraries. In other words, when the loader resolves a symbol, it has no info _where to pull that symbol from_. It just uses a list of libraries to search. Now, the symbol could itself be versioned, and that version might not exist in the more recent libgsl.

Comment: Is there a way to find out if the symbol is versioned? The reason I'm trying this is because I'm getting a symbol lookup error for `cblas_daxpy` and my theory is that it's not available in the older version.

Comment: you can use something like `objdump --dynamic-syms` to find all unresolved symbols. This will also show the symbol version requested. Although I'm confused that you get _additional_ unresolved symbols when using LD_PRELOAD. Maybe they come from the preloaded library?

Comment: Thanks -- sorry for the confusion, the unresolved symbol was from without the `LD_PRELOAD`. I haven't tried it with, yet: I don't know what triggers the error and just wanted to make sure it's not going to break things in other weird and wonderful ways before I try!

Comment: Btw if the suffix of a shared library is different, that usually means they're incompatible...